# Kotlin - Test inner Coroutines with delay using runBlockingTest

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have this piece of code :

```
fun setBlocked(blocked: Boolean) = viewModelScope.launchSafe(::handleExceptionsActive) {
    /**
     * Show loading after 500 ms to prevent from showing it if cloud functions are hot.
     */
    val loadingJob = launch { delay(500L); _loading.value = true }
    participantDataSource.setBlockedUser(contact.userId, blocked)

    loadingJob.cancelAndJoin()
    _loading.value = false
}
```

It does a Firebase Cloud Function call that might take a few seconds or just a few milliseconds depending on whether the Cloud Function is idle or not. What this code does is it triggers a loading `LiveData` at `true` after 500ms and then puts it back at `false`.

1. If the call takes a few milliseconds, then `loading.value = true` will never be called.
2. If the call takes a few seconds, then `loading.value = true` will be called.

I want to test the function `setBlocked()`.

The problem with this code is that I don't know how to test these two statements. I know I can test code using `delay()` with `runBlockingTest` and `advanceTimeBy()` but the thing is `loadingJob.cancel()` will be called before I call `advanceTimeBy()`.

How can I test it ? If you have suggestions on modifying the code to make it testable I'll be glad to here it too.

Edit : replaced `cancel()` by `cancelAndJoin()` as Marko Topolnik suggests.

Comment: One thing i can tell you that the code is racy, `cancel()` is an async operation, it doesn't return after cancellation has completed. So you may set `_loading = false` in the main coroutine and then a bit later the child coroutine sets it back to `true`.

Comment: Do I have to wait for the job to be completed ? I don't care that the cancellation has completed or not, as long as the inner coroutine checks for cancellation and doesn't call ``_loading.value = true`` after ``loadingJob.cancel()`` is called. I thought that since ``delay()``checks for cancellation I'll be safe on that.

Comment: There is no ordering between your main code proceeding to the statement after `cancel()` and the coroutine observing cancellation. It is fully possible that it is already past the `delay()` call when it observes it, and you get reordered execution of setting the flag to false, then true.